# Fastest way to peel 2 dozen bananas?

Tags: bananas, peeling, peel, mass-cooking

The bananas do not need to stay whole. Halves and quarters are fine

Surely kitchen professionals have come up with a way

(Note: apparently, banana peels are edible. I found an example of someone cutting the ends off and blending it into their smoothie, which is my use case. I'll try it, but still want a fast way of peeling)

Comment: What type & ripeness of bananas are we talking about?  A ripe cavendish is easy to peel by squeezing the bloom end pulling.  A green plantain is going to require steaming or a dip in boiling water.

Comment: @Joe Cavendish. Most of the peel yellow, some of it still green

Comment: Squeeze the end without the stalk and it should split easily, you can then just rip the two pieces in half and take out the middle. It's a lot faster and easier than pealing the "traditional" way

Comment: I suspect the skins would explode off, in a vacuum. Haven't tried it, but boiling banana fluids would have to build up pressure if the seal was good.

Answer (score 3):

When I've had to peel a bunch, I work in stages:

1. Top and tail every banana
2. Slit peel on every banana from one end to the other
3. Use thumbs to split open peel and invert over a bowl

You can rip through a whole case of bananas rather quickly that way.